# Where are indexes stored by android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Recently I switched from Android Studio 2.x to Android Studio 3 and while opening old codebase I find
[image]

Earlier I had the impression indexes are local to the project and will be reused even if I reinstall or upgrade android studio. Seems my assumptions were not correct. It would be great if someone can throw some light on the indexing process.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio 2023.1, they are stored in the following location:

```
$HOME/.cache/Google/<android studio version>/index
```